# Binding the same Collection to ComboBox and Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, prism

GitHub Link: https://github.com/babakin34/wpf_test/tree/master/WpfApp1

I have the following classes:

**VIEWMODELS**:

---

```
public class PersonVM : BindableBase
{
  public int ID { get; set; }

  private string _lastName;
  public string LastName
  {
      get { return _lastName; }
      set { SetProperty(ref _lastName, value); }
  }
}

public class MainVM : BindableBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<PersonVM> People { get; set; }

  private PersonVM _selectedPerson;
  public PersonVM SelectedPerson
  {
      get { return _selectedPerson; }
      set { SetProperty(ref _selectedPerson, value); }
  }

  public MainVM()
  {
      People = new ObservableCollection<PersonVM>()
      {
          new PersonVM()
          {
              ID = 1,
              LastName = "AA"
          },
          new PersonVM()
          {
              ID = 2,
              LastName = "BB"
          },
      };

      SelectedPerson = People.First();
  }
}
```

**VIEW**:

---

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="LastName" 
                  Margin="0,5,0,25"/>

        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

---

How can I achieve that the "MainVM.SelectedPerson" from ComboBox is notified when user selects the empty element, which is caused by the Datagrid's default last entry?

PS: I am using Prism, but the problem is not Prism related. You can replace BindableBase by INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: You should add `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"` to the DataGrid as well

Comment: You can set the CanUserAddRows property of the DataGrid to false to get rid of the last empty row. This is not an actual PersonVM that can be selected in the ComboBox but a placeholder for adding a new item to the DataGrid...

Comment: @mm8: I need the last row from DataGrid so the user can add new entries.

Comment: So what do you expect to show in the ComboBox when this row is selected?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: It doesn't have an effect on the ComboBox.

Comment: @mm8: The user has to be able to select an empty entry in the Combobox. From the usability point it is exactly what I want. The problem is that "MainVM.SelectedPerson" is not notified. (The actual code is much more complicated than what I posted.)

Comment: So your question is how to add an empty option to the ComboBox because as of now it inly contains the "AA" and "BB", right?

Comment: @mm8: Almost. If I would have only the ComboBox, I could have the empty option by adding a third PersonVM with an empty-string LastName. But since it gets automatically the last row from Datagrid, I would have in that case 2 empty options. So either I have to ignore/omit the last entry of DataGrid  in the Combobox and add manually an ampty PersonVM or use directly the last entry from DataGrid.

Comment: That's more to it than that. As mentioned, the last row in the DataGrid is not a PersonVM in your collection.

Comment: I added the GitHub Link if someone wants to test it.

Comment: @mm8: Ok. What would be the proper way than to achieve what I want? Is there a way to ignore DataGrid's last row in the ComboBox?

Comment: You could write some code in the view that sets the SelectedItem to the "empty" PersonVM object when the last row in the DataGrid is selected. This is not a view model thing but a view thing really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
The real issue here is a bit different than i thought at first. When selecting the insert row, you see in the output window that WPF is unable to cast a "NamedObject" into a "PersonVM". The Datagrid creates a NamedObject for the insert row to work with, but the binding simply does not work since it's of the wrong type.
The clean and easy solution is to create a converter to check if the object is of type PersonVM, otherwise return null (and not the NamedObject instance).

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is PersonVM)
            return value;
        return null;
    }
}
```

And in the xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
                  SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_OnSelectedCellsChanged"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson,
                                         Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}"
```

---

Old and dirty

Not the nicest way, but if you don't mind using the viewmodel (or abstracting it via an interface) in the codebehind you can use the "SelectionChanged" event to set the SelectedPerson in the ViewModel to null if any of the selected items are not of the type you need.

```
private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool invalidStuffSelected = false;
        //throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        foreach (var obj in DataGrid.SelectedItems)
        {
            if (!(obj is PersonVM))
                invalidStuffSelected = true;
        }
        MainVM vm = (MainVM) this.DataContext;
        if (invalidStuffSelected)
            vm.SelectedPerson = null;
    }
```

In your example the selectionmode "single" would make more sense since the combobox can only show one selected value.

Comment: I already solved it in a similar way. I only wanted to know if it would be possible without using code behind code or any dirty hack.